# Return value inside Facebook request OnComplete

Tags: android, facebook, asynccallback, facebook-requests

My doubt is, when i call a method below, the value is null, of course, because the object user it's not already populated, because will be populated inside Facebook request. So, the question is, how can i wait for the facebook complete and then return the right arraylist of users?

```
public ArrayList<User> getUsers(){

     ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
     User user = new User();
     //It's not the complete code 
     Facebook.resquest(){
         @Override
         onComplete(){
              for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){                
                users.add(user)
              }
         }
     }
   // The question is, what do i have to do for the below object 'll have the same value of    user object inside facebook request?

     return users;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Request.executeAndWait(request);`

in your code, before the return.